# Calling a function within a loop, "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, function

I have two functions at the top of my code. Below in a `while (i<1)` loop, I call one of the functions above. This works the first time, but the second time the function is called it displays an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Below is the code:

```
var i = 0;
var newBalance = 0;
var deposit = function(amountIn)
{
    newBalance = (newBalance + amountIn).toFixed(2);
};
var withdrawl = function(amountOut)
{
    newBalance = (newBalance - amountOut).toFixed(2);
};
var choice = prompt("Would you like to access your account?").toLowerCase();
if (choice === "yes"){
    while (i<1){

        var inOrOut = prompt("Are you making a deposit or a withdrawl?").toLowerCase();
        var strAmount = prompt("How much money are you trasfering?");
        var amount = parseFloat(strAmount);

        if (inOrOut === "deposit")
        {
            deposit(amount);
        }
        else if (inOrOut === "withdrawl")
        {
            withdrawl(amount);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("You did not enter a valid number");
        }

        console.log("Your new balance is $" + newBalance);
        var choiceTwo = prompt("Would you like to make another transaction?").toLowerCase();
        if (choiceTwo === "no")
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I sincerely hope this is not a real financial transaction....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, you set `newBalance` to a number. Calling either of your functions, however, will set `newBalance` to a string. (`toFixed` returns a string, not a number.) After that, `newBalance + amountIn` will also be a string (and be completely different from what you want — the `+` will denote string concatenation rather than addition), so it will not have a `toFixed` method. So you get the error you see.

To fix this, modify your functions so that they do *not* convert `newBalance` to a string. You should use `toFixed` only when you are displaying the balance:

```
console.log("Your new balance is $" + newBalance.toFixed(2));
```